# VBA Excel - Changing Text in one cell changes text in another Data Validation

Tags: excel, validation, vba

I've been looking around for an answer to this problem.

I have a worksheet with three cell's that are controlled by Data Validation, the cell contains employee names.

The cell headers are:

```
Personnel
Unallocated
On Leave
```

The cell with Unallocated lists all the personnel:

```
AARON MARQUIS
AIDAN MULLIGAN
CRAIG WILKINSON
CRISTIANO BORTOT
DEAN SHELFORD
DREW JOINES
GAVIN SHAW
HAYDEN THOMPSON
JAKE MOONEY
JASON MCGLYNN
JOHN MURPHY
MICHAEL VOGEL
NICHOLAS MADDERN
SEAMUS FEE
SEAN BLAKE
TRENT LAWRENCE
```

I'd like to update this cell as the user populates the Personnel & On Leave cell's by using a drop down list (Data Validation)

In other words, if the user populates the Personnel cell with a Personnel's name using the Data Validation drop down list, the Unallocated cell removes that name from the cell, this would also work for the On Leave cell.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code I'm using for the Data Validation is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo ExitSub

If Target.Column = 6 Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo ExitSub
    Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo ExitSub Else
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Newvalue = Target.Value
            Application.Undo
            Oldvalue = Target.Value
        If Oldvalue = "" Then
            Target.Value = Newvalue
        Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & vbLf & Newvalue
        Else
            Target.Value = Oldvalue
        End If
    End If
End If
End If
ExitSub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Marc, welcome to SO and thank you for your question. Currently we can't answer your question, because we lack crucial parts of information. Would you please be so kind to have a look at the how to ask page https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question using the edit button on the bottom of your post.

Comment: Well done, your question looks much better now. Just one question: Are all names stored in a single cell, or is every name stored in a seperate cell in one column?

Comment: Hi, all the names are stored in a single cell not a column, which makes things a bit difficult to reference to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First tip:  Rather than `Else: If`, just use `ElseIf`.  To elaborate:

```
If val1 Then
    Action1
Else: If val2 Then
    Action2
End If
End If
```

is the same as writing

```
If val1 Then
    Action1
ElseIf val2 Then
    Action2
End If
```

(The `:` has the same effect as starting a new-line, so the opposite of `_` which is "continues on next line")

Now, when you populate a cell, you want to change value of *another* cell, which you will need to define somewhere - here is a quick example, which you will need to modify to suit the quirks of your particular sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub 'Only change 1 cell
    If Target.Column <> 6 Then Exit Sub 'Column F only
    If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'Drop-Downs only

    Dim OldValue As String, NewValue As String, TempValue As String
    Dim rPersonnel As Range, rUnallocated As Range, rOnLeave As Range

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set rPersonel = Me.Cells(1, 6) 'Cell F1
    Set rUnallocated = Me.Cells(2, 6) 'Cell F2
    Set rOnLeave = Me.Cells(3, 6) 'Cell F3

    If Not Intersect(Target, Union(rPersonnel, rOnLeave)) Is Nothing Then
        NewValue = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        OldValue = Target.Value
        If OldValue = "" Then
            Target.Value = NewValue
        ElseIf InStr(1, OldValue, NewValue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = OldValue & vbLf & NewValue
        Else
            Target.Value = OldValue
        End If

        TempValue = Replace(Replace(rUnallocated.Value, NewValue, ""), vbLf & vbLf, vbLf) 'Remove from Unallocated and remove double-linebreaks
        TempValue = Replace(Replace(Replace("|" & TempValue & "|", "|" & vbLf, ""), vbLf & "|", ""), "|", "") 'Remove start/end linebreak
        rUnallocated.Value = TempValue
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, rPersonnel) Is Nothing Then 'You changed the "Personnel" list
        TempValue = Replace(Replace(rOnLeave.Value, NewValue, ""), vbLf & vbLf, vbLf) 'Remove from On Leave and remove double-linebreaks
        TempValue = Replace(Replace(Replace("|" & TempValue & "|", "|" & vbLf, ""), vbLf & "|", ""), "|", "") 'Remove start/end linebreak
        rOnLeave.Value = TempValue
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, rOnLeave) Is Nothing Then 'You changed the "OnLeave" list
        TempValue = Replace(Replace(rPersonnel.Value, NewValue, ""), vbLf & vbLf, vbLf) 'Remove from Personnel and remove double-linebreaks
        TempValue = Replace(Replace(Replace("|" & TempValue & "|", "|" & vbLf, ""), vbLf & "|", ""), "|", "") 'Remove start/end linebreak
        rPersonnel.Value = TempValue
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Prefect, with a little amount of massaging I got the code working really well, thanks very much

Comment: @MarcHeatley, if you found an answer helpfull, please let the community know by checking the checkmark next to the answer.